# Splitting a list into sublists using a separator list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to split a list into sublists using its sublist as a separator. The elements in the sublist must act like a starting point for list creation until the next element in the sublist comes up in the list.

It might be better to see it in an example:

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','1','11','111','x','y','z']
sep = ['b','11','y']
```

This is my desired output:

```
[['b','c','d','1'],['11','111','x'],['y','z']]
```

So far, I have the following:

```
import itertools

[list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x: x in sep)]
```

But this spits out `['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd', '1'], ['11'], ['111', 'x'], ['y'], ['z']]` which is not what I want.

Comment: Is there an `'a'` in your desired output?

Comment: @AnnZen No. Anything before the first element in separator must be ignored.

Comment: `a`  will be lost

Comment: Are all separators present in `lst`?

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually? `out = []; for x in lst: if x in sep: out.append(something) ...`

Comment: @DYZ yes, they are.

Comment: @wjandrea I had independently thought the same (and posted an answer to that effect) but now I am not confident that it is correct, because I think the point is that the separators are to be used _in order_, and that an element might happen to be **in** the list of separators but not be the **correct** separator to start the next sublist -- although this example does not expose that bug.

Comment: Can a separator appear more than once?

Comment: @NewbieAF Please can you clarify, do the separators have to be taken in order? For example, if `lst` were to start with `'11'`, should this be ignored (i.e. not start a list) because it is not the first separator even though it appears later on the list of separators? Or is it sufficient to match **any** of the separators in order to start a new list?

Comment: @alaniwi I'm pretty sure it's correct, I mean OP's code isn't order-dependent. You should undelete your answer! I'd upvote it! Just add your assumption(s) at the top like DYZ did, and you'll be covered. Namely the assumption is that separators are unordered, i.e. could be converted to a set.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks, have done - with assumption stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with an explicit loop.

This is on the assumption that the separators are unordered -- and indeed that it does not matter whether you use the same separator multiple times, or not at all -- just that whenever an element in `lst` matches *any* of the separators, it starts a new list.

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','1','11','111','x','y','z']
sep = ['b','11','y']

out = []
for el in lst:
    if el in sep:
        out.append([])
    if out:
        out[-1].append(el)
        
print(out)
```

Depending on the number of elements, it might be worth starting by creating a set from `sep` for more efficient inclusion testing.

Comment: The separators are indeed ordered, but each separator appears at most once. So your solutions still works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- Separators are not repeated.
- Separators occur in the same order in `lst` and `sep`.

Identify all potential start and end positions in the right order (the start of the next segment is the end of the previous one). Append `None` as the end of the last segment:

```
starts = sorted(lst.index(s) for s in sep)
ends = starts[1:] + [None]
```

Take a slice of the original list from each start position to the matching end position:

```
[lst[slice(start, end)] for start, end in zip(starts, ends)]
#[['b', 'c', 'd', '1'], ['11', '111', 'x'], ['y', 'z']]
```

The latter can be written using the asterisk notation:

```
[lst[slice(*ends)] for ends in zip(starts, ends)]
#[['b', 'c', 'd', '1'], ['11', '111', 'x'], ['y', 'z']]
```

Comment: Nice. I wonder if conceptually it is easier to grasp if the `+ [None]` is omitted from `starts` but then you have `ends = starts[1:] + [None]`.

Comment: Actually I'm going to edit it to do that - you can roll back if you disagree, obviously.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I changed my mind again -- or at least I wasn't sure -- but obviously too late... I'm going to ask the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use slices:

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','1','11','111','x','y','z']
sep = ['b','11','y']

l = [lst.index(i) for i in sep]+[len(lst)]
l = [lst[l[i-1]:v] for i,v in enumerate(l)][1:]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[['b', 'c', 'd', '1'], ['11', '111', 'x'], ['y', 'z']]
```

Comment: I think this will fail if a separator is repeated. Like lst = ['a','b','c','d','1','11','111','x','y','z','a',',b','c']
sep = ['b','11','y','b']

Comment: @WilfRosenbaum If a separator repeated, there could be multiple explanations as to what the output should be. The OP didn't specify.